# How to parse XML with text coordinates

Tags: excel, xml, python-3.x, text, xml-parsing

I extracted the information of the text from an XPS file into XML to retain the position of each character in the document using the fitz library in Python3.
I am trying to convert the XML into an excel spreadsheet for viewing purposes.

The data looks something like:

```
<page width="612" height="792">
<block bbox="122.28 93.597667 154.99869 157.9107">
    <line bbox="124.799999 93.597667 154.99869 103.6707" wmode="0" dir="1 0">
        <font name="Arial Regular" size="9.016425">
            <char quad="124.799999 93.597667 127.305049 93.597667 124.799999 103.6707 127.305049 103.6707" x="124.799999" y="101.759998" c=" "/>
            <char quad="127.30505 93.597667 129.8101 93.597667 127.30505 103.6707 129.8101 103.6707" x="127.30505" y="101.759998" c=" "/>
            <char quad="129.8101 93.597667 132.31516 93.597667 129.8101 103.6707 132.31516 103.6707" x="129.8101" y="101.759998" c=" "/>
            <char quad="132.31516 93.597667 134.8202 93.597667 132.31516 103.6707 134.8202 103.6707" x="132.31516" y="101.759998" c=" "/>
            <char quad="134.82022 93.597667 137.32527 93.597667 134.82022 103.6707 137.32527 103.6707" x="134.82022" y="101.759998" c=" "/>
            <char quad="137.32527 93.597667 142.33979 93.597667 137.32527 103.6707 142.33979 103.6707" x="137.32527" y="101.759998" c="1"/>
            <char quad="142.33977 93.597667 147.35428 93.597667 142.33977 103.6707 147.35428 103.6707" x="142.33977" y="101.759998" c="8"/>
            <char quad="147.47913 93.597667 152.49364 93.597667 147.47913 103.6707 152.49364 103.6707" x="147.47913" y="101.759998" c="2"/>
            <char quad="152.49364 93.597667 154.99869 93.597667 152.49364 103.6707 154.99869 103.6707" x="152.49364" y="101.759998" c=" "/>
        </font>
    </line>
    <line bbox="127.31999 104.39767 154.93863 114.4707" wmode="0" dir="1 0">
        <font name="Arial Regular" size="9.016425">
            <char quad="127.31999 104.39767 129.82505 104.39767 127.31999 114.4707 129.82505 114.4707" x="127.31999" y="112.56" c=" "/>
            <char quad="129.82505 104.39767 132.3301 104.39767 129.82505 114.4707 132.3301 114.4707" x="129.82505" y="112.56" c=" "/>
            <char quad="132.33011 104.39767 134.83516 104.39767 132.33011 114.4707 134.83516 114.4707" x="132.33011" y="112.56" c=" "/>
            <char quad="134.83516 104.39767 137.34021 104.39767 134.83516 114.4707 137.34021 114.4707" x="134.83516" y="112.56" c=" "/>
            <char quad="137.34021 104.39767 139.84526 104.39767 137.34021 114.4707 139.84526 114.4707" x="137.34021" y="112.56" c=" "/>
            <char quad="139.84528 104.39767 142.35033 104.39767 139.84528 114.4707 142.35033 114.4707" x="139.84528" y="112.56" c=" "/>
            <char quad="142.46004 104.39767 147.47455 104.39767 142.46004 114.4707 147.47455 114.4707" x="142.46004" y="112.56" c="2"/>
            <char quad="147.41907 104.39767 152.43358 104.39767 147.41907 114.4707 152.43358 114.4707" x="147.41907" y="112.56" c="0"/>
            <char quad="152.43358 104.39767 154.93863 104.39767 152.43358 114.4707 154.93863 114.4707" x="152.43358" y="112.56" c=" "/>
        </font>
    </line>
    <line bbox="124.799999 115.317668 154.99869 125.3907" wmode="0" dir="1 0">
        <font name="Arial Regular" size="9.016425">
            <char quad="124.799999 115.317668 127.305049 115.317668 124.799999 125.3907 127.305049 125.3907" x="124.799999" y="123.479999" c=" "/>
            <char quad="127.30505 115.317668 129.8101 115.317668 127.30505 125.3907 129.8101 125.3907" x="127.30505" y="123.479999" c=" "/>
            <char quad="129.8101 115.317668 132.31516 115.317668 129.8101 125.3907 132.31516 125.3907" x="129.8101" y="123.479999" c=" "/>
            <char quad="132.31516 115.317668 134.8202 115.317668 132.31516 125.3907 134.8202 125.3907" x="132.31516" y="123.479999" c=" "/>
            <char quad="134.82022 115.317668 137.32527 115.317668 134.82022 125.3907 137.32527 125.3907" x="134.82022" y="123.479999" c=" "/>
            <char quad="137.32527 115.317668 142.33979 115.317668 137.32527 125.3907 142.33979 125.3907" x="137.32527" y="123.479999" c="1"/>
            <char quad="142.33977 115.317668 147.35428 115.317668 142.33977 125.3907 147.35428 125.3907" x="142.33977" y="123.479999" c="4"/>
            <char quad="147.47913 115.317668 152.49364 115.317668 147.47913 125.3907 152.49364 125.3907" x="147.47913" y="123.479999" c="1"/>
            <char quad="152.49364 115.317668 154.99869 115.317668 152.49364 125.3907 154.99869 125.3907" x="152.49364" y="123.479999" c=" "/>
        </font>
    </line>
    <line bbox="122.28 126.11767 154.93267 136.1907" wmode="0" dir="1 0">
        <font name="Arial Regular" size="9.016425">
            <char quad="122.28 126.11767 124.78505 126.11767 122.28 136.1907 124.78505 136.1907" x="122.28" y="134.28" c=" "/>
            <char quad="124.78505 126.11767 127.2901 126.11767 124.78505 136.1907 127.2901 136.1907" x="124.78505" y="134.28" c=" "/>
            <char quad="127.2901 126.11767 129.79515 126.11767 127.2901 136.1907 129.79515 136.1907" x="127.2901" y="134.28" c=" "/>
            <char quad="129.79517 126.11767 132.30022 126.11767 129.79517 136.1907 132.30022 136.1907" x="129.79517" y="134.28" c=" "/>
            <char quad="132.30022 126.11767 137.31473 126.11767 132.30022 136.1907 137.31473 136.1907" x="132.30022" y="134.28" c="1"/>
            <char quad="137.31472 126.11767 142.32923 126.11767 137.31472 136.1907 142.32923 136.1907" x="137.31472" y="134.28" c="4"/>
            <char quad="142.45407 126.11767 147.46858 126.11767 142.45407 136.1907 147.46858 136.1907" x="142.45407" y="134.28" c="7"/>
            <char quad="147.41312 126.11767 152.42763 126.11767 147.41312 136.1907 152.42763 136.1907" x="147.41312" y="134.28" c="2"/>
            <char quad="152.42761 126.11767 154.93267 126.11767 152.42761 136.1907 154.93267 136.1907" x="152.42761" y="134.28" c=" "/>
        </font>
    </line>
    <line bbox="122.28 136.91767 154.93267 146.9907" wmode="0" dir="1 0">
        <font name="Arial Regular" size="9.016425">
            <char quad="122.28 136.91767 124.78505 136.91767 122.28 146.9907 124.78505 146.9907" x="122.28" y="145.08" c=" "/>
            <char quad="124.78505 136.91767 127.2901 136.91767 124.78505 146.9907 127.2901 146.9907" x="124.78505" y="145.08" c=" "/>
            <char quad="127.2901 136.91767 129.79515 136.91767 127.2901 146.9907 129.79515 146.9907" x="127.2901" y="145.08" c=" "/>
            <char quad="129.79517 136.91767 132.30022 136.91767 129.79517 146.9907 132.30022 146.9907" x="129.79517" y="145.08" c=" "/>
            <char quad="132.30022 136.91767 137.31473 136.91767 132.30022 146.9907 137.31473 146.9907" x="132.30022" y="145.08" c="2"/>
            <char quad="137.31472 136.91767 142.32923 136.91767 137.31472 146.9907 142.32923 146.9907" x="137.31472" y="145.08" c="9"/>
            <char quad="142.45407 136.91767 147.46858 136.91767 142.45407 146.9907 147.46858 146.9907" x="142.45407" y="145.08" c="3"/>
            <char quad="147.41312 136.91767 152.42763 136.91767 147.41312 146.9907 152.42763 146.9907" x="147.41312" y="145.08" c="4"/>
            <char quad="152.42761 136.91767 154.93267 136.91767 152.42761 146.9907 154.93267 146.9907" x="152.42761" y="145.08" c=" "/>
        </font>
    </line>
    <line bbox="124.799999 147.83768 154.99869 157.9107" wmode="0" dir="1 0">
        <font name="Arial Regular" size="9.016425">
            <char quad="124.799999 147.83768 127.305049 147.83768 124.799999 157.9107 127.305049 157.9107" x="124.799999" y="156" c=" "/>
            <char quad="127.30505 147.83768 129.8101 147.83768 127.30505 157.9107 129.8101 157.9107" x="127.30505" y="156" c=" "/>
            <char quad="129.8101 147.83768 132.31516 147.83768 129.8101 157.9107 132.31516 157.9107" x="129.8101" y="156" c=" "/>
            <char quad="132.31516 147.83768 134.8202 147.83768 132.31516 157.9107 134.8202 157.9107" x="132.31516" y="156" c=" "/>
            <char quad="134.82022 147.83768 137.32527 147.83768 134.82022 157.9107 137.32527 157.9107" x="134.82022" y="156" c=" "/>
            <char quad="137.32527 147.83768 142.33979 147.83768 137.32527 157.9107 142.33979 157.9107" x="137.32527" y="156" c="7"/>
            <char quad="142.33977 147.83768 147.35428 147.83768 142.33977 157.9107 147.35428 157.9107" x="142.33977" y="156" c="6"/>
            <char quad="147.47913 147.83768 152.49364 147.83768 147.47913 157.9107 152.49364 157.9107" x="147.47913" y="156" c="4"/>
            <char quad="152.49364 147.83768 154.99869 147.83768 152.49364 157.9107 154.99869 157.9107" x="152.49364" y="156" c=" "/>
        </font>
    </line>
</block>
```

I need it formatted like (when parsed into an excel spreadsheet):

```
 182      3% 
  20      0% 
 141      3% 
1472     27% 
2934     53% 
 764     14%
```

I tried using the Python3 xml.etree.ElementTree library and looping through the blocks in the page. The problem is I have no idea how to format the text such that the consecutive blocks appear exactly in their so called x,y coordinates because there are other blocks with x,y coordinates far to the corner of the pages. Does anyone have an idea on how to keep the formatting?

Comment: please explain, how your output **182 | 3%,  20 | 0%..** is generated out of the xml.

Comment: @MigB The first column is from the data shown, while the second column is not included in the data. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: how do you get an 182 out of your data? do your columns have a key? ...

Comment: @MigB There is a c attribute for the char line. So combining all the c values for the block of lines gives 182 plus a few spacings for the first block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `ET.findall()`function to iterate over every record (**line** inside **block** and **char** inside **line**).

Inside the second loop you can concatenate the (string-) numbers given in `char.attrib['c']` and save them in a list.

To write the values into excel, you could try [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

```
XMLPATH = "data.xml"
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from openpyxl import Workbook

#parse xml-file
tree = ET.parse(XMLPATH)
root = tree.getroot()

#store values into list
#prepare SUM
column1 = list()
SUM = 0
for line in tree.findall('block/line'):
    temp_charstring = str()
    for char in line.findall('font/char'):
        temp_charstring += str(char.attrib['c']) #-> '   182 ', '    20 ', ...
    column1.append(temp_charstring.strip(' ')) #> ['182', '20', '141', ... ]
    SUM += int(temp_charstring.strip(' '))

#create xlsx sheet
wb= Workbook()
ws = wb.active

#write into xlsx sheet
idx = 0
for i in (column1):
    print(i)
    idx+=1

    ws['{cell}'.format(cell=('A'+str(idx)))] = int(i)   
    #--> ['A1'], ['A2'], ... = 182, 20, ...

    ws['{cell}'.format(cell=('B'+str(idx)))] = int(i)/SUM*100 
    #--> ['B1'], ['B2'], ... = 3.30, 0.36, ...

#save xlsx sheet
wb.save("data.xlsx")
```

Comment: I have to sort out the data in the loop properly but ET.findall() is the one I need. Thanks @MigB